# I need to create an algorithm that reads people's height and gender until a height less than or equal to 0 is entered

Tags: python

alt = input('Enter the height of the person: ')
gender = input('Enter the person's gender: ')

while alt and sex:
alt = input('Enter the height of the person: ')
gender = input('Enter the person's gender: ')

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
heights = []
genders = []

while True:
   try:
      height = float(input('Enter the height of the person: '))
   except:
      print('Error: you must insert numerical value')
   
   # exit condition:
   if height <= 0:
      break
   
   gender = input("Enter the person's gender: ")
   if gender != 'male' and gender != 'female': # or whatever you want
      print('Error: only "male" or "female" can be accepted')
   
   heights.append(height)
   genders.append(gender)

# do something with iputs
....
```

**Edit**: at the end of the `while`, you have that `heights` and `weights` have same size. Furthermore, the `i-th` element of `heights` is related to the `i-th` of genders. That's why, iterating once on these arrays, you can answer both the questions:

```py
male_avg = 1.73
female_avg = 1.60
male_count = 0
female_count = 0
for i in range(len(heights)):
   if genders[i] == 'female' and heights[i] > female_avg:
      female_count += 1
   if genders[i] == 'male' and heights[i] > male_avg:
      male_count += 1
```

You can print the `male_count` and `female_counts` varaibles when loop ends.

Comment: also the exercise asks how many women on the list are above the national average height (1.60m) for women and how many are below; b) how many men on the list are above the national average height (1.73m) for men and how many are below

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help even if i'm not an expert in python. Unfortunately, I don't really understood what are your problem ?

I think a simple while statement should do the work, like this :

```
alt = input('Enter the height of the person')
while((alt > 0)):
     gender = input('Enter the gender of the person')
     alt = input('Enter the height of the person')
```

I hope it helped you
Good luck :)